# quick jquery each loop question

Tags: jquery

If i write

```
$('.myclass').each(function () {});
```

and there are no elements of myclass on a particular page, will it create problems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

no you will be fine, it will basically do nothing. If jQuery finds no elements named ".myclass" it just continues on.